# add_meta_box (Will display only in specific page admin WordPress)

Tags: plugins, php, themes

I am wondering how to add meta box in WordPress specific page admin, I mean when I create meta_box with code snippet below provided from source tutorial is really perfect and effective but one thing that I need to control is display that meta_box only in specific page for instance: pretend I have two page in my WordPress project named Home and About.

When I create meta_box by default the meta_box that I add will display on the same page admin back end, imagined when I clicked edit button to Home and About page my meta box will appear in both page. What I want is make a meta_box only show in “Home” admin backend page when I click the edit page.

My goal is set different meta_box in every different page, meaning the users specially the blog editor expect different meta_box_field in different page when they click edit button in each page, That is the thing I can’t figure out can you help me to solve that problem

```
/*
Plugin Name: Meta Box Example
Description: Example demonstrating how to add Meta Boxes.
Plugin URI:  https://plugin-planet.com/
Author:      Jeff Starr
Version:     1.0
*/

// register meta box
function myplugin_add_meta_box() {

    $post_types = array( 'post', 'page' );

    foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) {

        add_meta_box(
            'myplugin_meta_box',         // Unique ID of meta box
            'MyPlugin Meta Box',         // Title of meta box
            'myplugin_display_meta_box', // Callback function
            $post_type                   // Post type
        );

    }

}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'myplugin_add_meta_box' );

// display meta box
function myplugin_display_meta_box( $post ) {

    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_myplugin_meta_key', true );

    wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'myplugin_meta_box_nonce' );

    ?>

    <label for="myplugin-meta-box">Field Description</label>
    <select id="myplugin-meta-box" name="myplugin-meta-box">
        <option value="">Select option...</option>
        <option value="option-1" <?php selected( $value, 'option-1' ); ?>>Option 1</option>
        <option value="option-2" <?php selected( $value, 'option-2' ); ?>>Option 2</option>
        <option value="option-3" <?php selected( $value, 'option-3' ); ?>>Option 3</option>
    </select>

<?php

}

// save meta box
function myplugin_save_meta_box( $post_id ) {

    $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
    $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );

    $is_valid_nonce = false;

    if ( isset( $_POST[ 'myplugin_meta_box_nonce' ] ) ) {

        if ( wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'myplugin_meta_box_nonce' ], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) {

            $is_valid_nonce = true;

        }

    }

    if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce ) return;

    if ( array_key_exists( 'myplugin-meta-box', $_POST ) ) {

        update_post_meta(
            $post_id,                                            // Post ID
            '_myplugin_meta_key',                                // Meta key
            sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'myplugin-meta-box' ] ) // Meta value
        );

    }

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'myplugin_save_meta_box' );
```

Is there any condition or function to do that you will recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/* Add meta boxs for particular pages */

function meta_set_particular_page() {
    $post_id = $_GET['post'] ? $_GET['post'] : $_POST['post_ID'];
    $current_page_title = get_the_title($post_id);
    if ($current_page_title == 'home') {
        add_meta_box('Home_page', 'Home Name:', 'only_home', 'page', 'side', 'core');
    }
    if($current_page_title == 'about'){
        add_meta_box('About_page', 'About Name:', 'only_about', 'page', 'side', 'core');
    }
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'meta_set_particular_page');

/* Add custom meta box for home page */

function only_home($post) {
    $home_page = esc_html(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'home_page', true));
    ?>
    <table style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 20%">Name</td>
            <td style="width: 40%">
                <input type="text" size="70" name="home_page" placeholder="Home Name" value="<?php echo $home_page; ?>">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}

/*Add custom meta box for about page*/

function only_about($post) {
    $about_page = esc_html(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'about_page', true));
    ?>
    <table style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 20%">Name</td>
            <td style="width: 40%">
                <input type="text" size="50" name="about_page" placeholder="About Name" value="<?php echo $about_page; ?>">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}

/*Save custom post meta values*/

function custom_metabox_fields($custom_metabox_id) {
    if (isset($_POST['home_page'])) {
        update_post_meta($custom_metabox_id, 'home_page', $_POST['home_page']);
    }
     if (isset($_POST['about_page'])) {
        update_post_meta($custom_metabox_id, 'about_page', $_POST['about_page']);
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'custom_metabox_fields', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Hey, @vishwa nice code. Your answer is off to a good start. Please consider explaining how and why this code solves the problem so others can learn from it. Check the [guide to answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for further advice.

Comment: You are awesome! Thanks you save my day!

Answer (score 1):

```
**check via post ID for a specific page or post**


$post_id = $_GET['post'] ? $_GET['post'] : $_POST['post_ID'] ;
if ($post_id == '84')
{
    add_meta_box();
}

**OR
check via template page name just as below**



$template_file = get_post_meta($post_id,'_wp_page_template',TRUE);
if ($template_file == 'home.php')
{
    add_meta_box();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very appreciate